# How to retain imageButton instant state on screen rotate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imagebutton

I have an imageButton that i put a color tint on (for whatever color the user has specified from a color picker)... And it works great until I rotate the screen. Then, when I try to change the colorFilter, the imageButton is null. How can I retain the imageButton instance? It's not parcelable, or serializable... So onSaveInstanceState won't work...

My understanding is that when the screen is rotated, the fragment reloads everything so the imageButton shouldn't be null.

Ok - I have some clarification...

I have a MainActivity with tabs and fragments in the tabs using a ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter.

Then I'm using a ColorPickerDialogFragment to select a color and change the imageButton color to that color.

I show the color picker like this:

```
ColorPickerDialogFragment dialog = ColorPickerDialogFragment.newInstance(BACKGROUND_COLOR_PICKER, "Color Picker", null, backgroundCurrentColor, false);
                    dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DarkPickerDialogTheme);
                    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "pre_dialog");
```

Works until I rotate the screen... then the imageButton in the fragment (within the ViewPager) is null.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the getFragmentManager() not returning the correct fragment reference after rotate due to the ViewPager?

Comment: What about saving user's selection in a variable, save it in `onSaveInstanceState` and apply the stored value to your `ImageButton` in `onCreate()` after screen rotation?

Comment: When you rotate the device your fragment should go through the onCreateView and onViewCreated functions, where you should be getting a reference to your button. Could you post your fragment code so we can figure out why it's null the 2nd time?

Comment: I added some more info... Hopefully that makes a bit more sense...